# How to compare currentDate with ExpirationDate?

Tags: javascript

guys!
I was doing kata on codewars and stuck with this one.

I've passed almost all tests there 24 of 25.
I am getting message --  Expected: true, instead got: undefined
2013,11,8 is currentDate and 2014,11,5  is ExpirationDate  in this particular test.
But I can't find where is a mistake.
Thank you so much!

```
function checkCoupon(enteredCode, correctCode, currentDate, expirationDate) {
var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
if (enteredCode === correctCode) {
    function stringToArray(string) {
        var dateCheck = string.replace(',', '').split(' ');
        months.indexOf(dateCheck[0]);
        dateCheck[0] = months.indexOf(dateCheck[0]) + 1
        for (i in dateCheck) {
            dateCheck[i] = parseInt(dateCheck[i])
        }
        dateCheck.splice(2, 0, dateCheck[0])
        dateCheck.shift()
        return dateCheck.reverse()
    }
    var currentDateVar = stringToArray(currentDate)
    var expDateVar = stringToArray(expirationDate)  
    for (var i = 0; i < currentDateVar.length; i++) {
        if (currentDateVar[i] <= expDateVar[i]) {
            if (currentDateVar[i] <= expDateVar[i] || (currentDateVar[i] > expDateVar[i] && currentDateVar[i - 1] < expDateVar[i - 1])) {
                
                if (currentDateVar[i] < expDateVar[i] || currentDateVar[i] < expDateVar[i]) {
                    console.log(`${currentDateVar} is less ${expDateVar} so it means that cupon works`)
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            console.log('cupon is outdated')
            return false
        }
    }
}
else {
    console.log('validation didn\'t succesful')
    return false
}
```

}

Comment: To make this a proper question, we really need to know what it is you're trying to do. At the moment all you've given us is a block of code with a cryptic error message. Explaining what the goal is, your approach, and what's going wrong will greatly increase your chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: So, basically this function is workable, but I have some problems in the control flow section. Probably I didn't build it correctly, so the validation causes an error in some particular cases.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the kata for you.First of all you failed at these dates :

[ 5, 7, 2000 ]
[ 5, 7, 2000 ]

So you must check for the same currentDate and expirationDate.If you arrange your code like this you can pass all the tests

```
if (currentDateVar[i] <= expDateVar[i]) {
        if (currentDateVar[i] <= expDateVar[i] || (currentDateVar[i] > expDateVar[i] 
&& currentDateVar[i - 1] < expDateVar[i - 1])) {
            
            if (currentDateVar[i] < expDateVar[i] ) {
                console.log(`${currentDateVar} is less ${expDateVar} so it means that cupon works`)
                return true
            }
          
        }
      if(currentDateVar[i] <= expDateVar[i] && currentDateVar[i - 1] <= expDateVar[i - 1] && currentDateVar[i - 2] <= expDateVar[i - 2] ){
        return true;
      }
    }
```